# IPTABLES issue - trying to DROP any connections to 3306 except from 127.0.0.1 and VPN

Tags: mysql, vpn, iptables

I have a VPS where I have successfully set up VPN. I connect with OpenVPN client. The VPN server interface is 10.8.0.1 and the client receives 10.8.0.? IP. And I am able to ping 10.8.0.1. I also seem to be able to do telnet to 10.8.0.1:80, 10.8.0.1:443, etc standard ports with working services on them but not 10.8.0.1:3306.

This is the VPN connection as printed by ifconfig:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:383 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:358 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:29356 (28.6 KiB)  TX bytes:149232 (145.7 KiB)
```

MySQL is not binded to any IP, so it receives connections from anywhere. I want to cut it's visibility by IPTABLES.

Then I added these rules to IPTABLES:

```
# allow connections from the vpn
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.8.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
# allow local connections eg your scripts running locally
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
# deny any other attempts of connecting to mysql
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

Now I'm able to connect to 127.0.0.1 from the server itself. I'm not able to connect to the server by it's public IP. And I'm not able to connect to it through 10.8.0.1 (VPN IP).

This is my full IPTABLES:

```
[root@ddinvps mail]# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:1723
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
icmp_packets  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
tcp_packets  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:3306

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain icmp_packets (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 0
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 3
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 11
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8
DROP       icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain tcp_packets (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:26
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  10.3.124.200         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:9102
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:143
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:993
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10000
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The packets are being filtered by the `tcp_packets` chain. This is because your `iptables -A` command has added the new rules to the end of the `INPUT` chain and the filter works on first match wins. The easiest way to solve your problem is to add your rules to the beginning of the `INPUT` chain using the `iptables -I` command e.g.

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 10.8.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

etc. which will insert your new rules at the beginning of the Chain.

Answer (score 1):

It's obviuos your tcp_packets chain drops traffic before it hits your rule.

Either add this rule in the begining of tcp_packets chain, or in INPUT chain, but before jumping tcp_packets

Comment: Hey, thank you! I accepted the other answer as it appeared while I was trying to find how to achieve what you suggested (but upvoted yours as well as it is 100% true). I might look dummy to you guys, but while I feel certain comfort working under Linux, I've been reading about iptables for the last few hours and I'm still quite confused about such trivial things.